# No filesystem permissions within gem5 SE-mode

Tags: gem5

In learning how to use gem5, I'm currently following the gem5 bootcamp 2022 examples.
Specifically, an example that lists the contents of a directory ([gem5 bootcamp 2022: Using SE mode, traffic generators, etc. - 59:58](https://www.youtube.com/live/7QX-QdBtFGY?feature=share&t=3598)) (code below).

In the recording, executing the binary lists the directory contents as expected (whether run within gem5 or directly).
On my system (Linux Mint with kernel `x86_64 Linux 5.4.0-150-generic`) the program also lists the files as expected when run directly (within docker, but outside gem5):

```
$ materials/using-gem5/03-running/example2/dir_example
cwd: /data
getuid: 1000
geteuid: 1000
/data  st_ino: 65863815
/data  st_mode: 16893
/data  st_ino: 65863815
/data  st_mode: 16893
/  st_ino: 75415865
/  st_mode: 16877
baddir/  st_ino: 75415865
baddir/  st_mode: 16877
ERROR No such file or directory
List of Files & Folders:
_includes, docker, _data, creating-content.md, .gitmodules, gem5, m5out-simulator-use, .., .gitignore, modules, .vscode, m5out, m5out-se-example, README.md, gem5_stubgen.py, _sass, LICENSE, hints.txt, docker.sh, Makefile, .git, ., gem5-resources, m5out-dir-example, Gemfile, requirements.txt, materials, .devcontainer, .pre-commit-config.yaml, index.md, _layouts, x86-full-system-m5out.zip, _config.yml, assets, m5out_,
```

However, when I run the binary within gem5, it seems like the program does not have permissions to access the filesystem for some reason, and prints `Error Occurred!Not a directory`:

```
$ /gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt -d m5out-dir-example materials/using-gem5/03-running/simple.py "materials/using-gem5/03-running/example2/dir_example"
gem5 Simulator System.  https://www.gem5.org
gem5 is copyrighted software; use the --copyright option for details.

gem5 version 22.1.0.0
gem5 compiled Jun  3 2023 10:20:55
gem5 started Jun 16 2023 08:13:52
gem5 executing on b7dcffa1dcac, pid 206
command line: /gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt -d m5out-dir-example materials/using-gem5/03-running/simple.py materials/using-gem5/03-running/example2/dir_example

Global frequency set at 1000000000000 ticks per second
build/X86/mem/dram_interface.cc:690: warn: DRAM device capacity (8192 Mbytes) does not match the address range assigned (512 Mbytes)
0: system.remote_gdb: listening for remote gdb on port 7000
Beginning simulation!
build/X86/sim/simulate.cc:192: info: Entering event queue @ 0.  Starting simulation...
build/X86/sim/mem_state.cc:443: info: Increasing stack size by one page.
build/X86/sim/syscall_emul.cc:74: warn: ignoring syscall set_robust_list(...)
build/X86/sim/syscall_emul.cc:74: warn: ignoring syscall rseq(...)
build/X86/sim/syscall_emul.cc:74: warn: ignoring syscall mprotect(...)
build/X86/sim/syscall_emul.cc:74: warn: ignoring syscall mprotect(...)
build/X86/sim/syscall_emul.cc:74: warn: ignoring syscall mprotect(...)
build/X86/sim/syscall_emul.cc:74: warn: ignoring syscall mprotect(...)
build/X86/sim/syscall_emul.cc:74: warn: ignoring syscall mprotect(...)
build/X86/sim/syscall_emul.cc:74: warn: ignoring syscall mprotect(...)
build/X86/arch/x86/generated/exec-ns.cc.inc:27: warn: instruction 'palignr_Vdq_Wdq_Ib' unimplemented
build/X86/arch/x86/generated/exec-ns.cc.inc:27: warn: instruction 'palignr_Vdq_Wdq_Ib' unimplemented
build/X86/arch/x86/generated/exec-ns.cc.inc:27: warn: instruction 'palignr_Vdq_Wdq_Ib' unimplemented
build/X86/arch/x86/generated/exec-ns.cc.inc:27: warn: instruction 'palignr_Vdq_Wdq_Ib' unimplemented
cwd: /data/
getuid: 100
geteuid: 100
/data/  st_ino: 85899362813
/data/  st_mode: 0
/data  st_ino: 85899362813
/data  st_mode: 0
/  st_ino: 4294984173
/  st_mode: 0
baddir/  st_ino: 4294984173
baddir/  st_mode: 0
ERROR No such file or directory

Error Occurred!Not a directory

Exiting @ tick 183726937000 because exiting with last active thread context
```

It seems that when executing the program within gem5, it is run by a different user (different uid) and therefore has no permissions (st_mode: 0) for the filesystem.
Simply setting `process.uid.value` & co (in `materials/using-gem5/03-running/simple.py`) did not help.

**How can I get gem5 to run the program with permissions for the filesystem, such that it successfully lists the directory contents?**

---

Workload code (compiled to `materials/using-gem5/03-running/example2/dir_example` with `g++ -o dir_example dir_example.c* -L/gem5/util/m5/build/x86/out -lm5 -I/gem5/include`):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<cerrno>
#include<cstring>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int ret;

    char cwd[0x1000] = {0};
    getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
    std::cout << "cwd: " << cwd << "\n";

    std::cout << "getuid: " << getuid() << "\n";
    std::cout << "geteuid: " << geteuid() << "\n";

    struct stat statbuf;
    char* paths[] = {cwd, (char*)"/data", (char*)"/", (char*)"baddir/", nullptr};
    for (int i = 0; paths[i]; i++) {
        ret = stat(paths[i], &statbuf);
        std::cout << paths[i] << "  st_ino: " << statbuf.st_ino << "\n";
        std::cout << paths[i] << "  st_mode: " << statbuf.st_mode << "\n";
        if (ret == -1) { \
            std::cout << "ERROR " << std::strerror(errno) << "\n"; \
        }
    }

    struct dirent *d;
    DIR *dr;
    dr = opendir(cwd);
    if (dr!=NULL) {
        std::cout<<"List of Files & Folders:\n";
        for (d=readdir(dr); d!=NULL; d=readdir(dr)) {
            std::cout<<d->d_name<< ", ";
        }
        closedir(dr);
    }
    else {
        std::cout<<"\nError Occurred!" << std::strerror(errno) << "\n";
    }
    std::cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`materials/using-gem5/03-running/simple.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Copyright (c) 2015 Jason Power
# All rights reserved.
#
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
# modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
# met: redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
# notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer;
# redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
# notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
# documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution;
# neither the name of the copyright holders nor the names of its
# contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from
# this software without specific prior written permission.
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
# "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
# LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
# A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
# OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
# SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
# LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
# DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
# THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
# (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
# OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

""" This file creates a barebones system and executes 'hello', a simple Hello
World application.
See Part 1, Chapter 2: Creating a simple configuration script in the
learning_gem5 book for more information about this script.

IMPORTANT: If you modify this file, it's likely that the Learning gem5 book
           also needs to be updated. For now, email Jason <power.jg@gmail.com>

"""

# import the m5 (gem5) library created when gem5 is built
import m5
# import all of the SimObjects
from m5.objects import *
# from m5.core import setInterpDir
import sys
from pdb import set_trace as st

BINARY = "materials/using-gem5/03-running/example1/se_example" #"/workspaces/gem5-bootcamp-env/exampleBin"
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    BINARY = sys.argv[1]

m5.defines.buildEnv['TARGET_ISA'] = 'x86' # TARGET_ISA has been removed

# create the system we are going to simulate
system = System()

# Set the clock frequency of the system (and all of its children)
system.clk_domain = SrcClockDomain()
system.clk_domain.clock = '1GHz'
system.clk_domain.voltage_domain = VoltageDomain()

# Set up the system
system.mem_mode = 'timing'               # Use timing accesses
system.mem_ranges = [AddrRange('512MB')] # Create an address range

# Create a simple CPU
system.cpu = TimingSimpleCPU()

# Create a memory bus, a system crossbar, in this case
system.membus = SystemXBar()

# Hook the CPU ports up to the membus
system.cpu.icache_port = system.membus.cpu_side_ports
system.cpu.dcache_port = system.membus.cpu_side_ports

# create the interrupt controller for the CPU and connect to the membus
system.cpu.createInterruptController()

# For x86 only, make sure the interrupts are connected to the memory
# Note: these are directly connected to the memory bus and are not cached
if m5.defines.buildEnv['TARGET_ISA'] == "x86":
    system.cpu.interrupts[0].pio = system.membus.mem_side_ports
    system.cpu.interrupts[0].int_requestor = system.membus.cpu_side_ports
    system.cpu.interrupts[0].int_responder = system.membus.mem_side_ports

# Create a DDR3 memory controller and connect it to the membus
system.mem_ctrl = MemCtrl()
system.mem_ctrl.dram = DDR3_1600_8x8()
system.mem_ctrl.dram.range = system.mem_ranges[0]
system.mem_ctrl.port = system.membus.mem_side_ports

# Connect the system up to the membus
system.system_port = system.membus.cpu_side_ports

# get ISA for the binary to run.
isa = str(m5.defines.buildEnv['TARGET_ISA']).lower()

# Default to running 'hello', use the compiled ISA to find the binary
# grab the specific path to the binary
thispath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

binary = BINARY

# setInterpDir("/usr/aarch64-linux-genu/")
# system.redirect_paths = [RedirectPath(app_path="/lib", host_paths=["/usr/aarch64-linux-genu/lib"])]

system.workload = SEWorkload.init_compatible(binary)

# Create a process for a simple "Hello World" application
process = Process()

# TODO: figure out how to get access to the filesystem from the workload binary
# Just overwriting (e)uid and (e)gid values here did not work.
#process.uid.value = 1000
#process.euid.value = 1000
#process.gid.value = 1000
#process.egid.value = 1000

# Set the command
# cmd is a list which begins with the executable (like argv)
process.cmd = [binary]
# Set the cpu to use the process as its workload and create thread contexts
system.cpu.workload = process
system.cpu.createThreads()

# set up the root SimObject and start the simulation
root = Root(full_system = False, system = system)
# instantiate all of the objects we've created above
m5.instantiate()

#st()
print("Beginning simulation!")
exit_event = m5.simulate()
print('Exiting @ tick %i because %s' % (m5.curTick(), exit_event.getCause()))
```

I'm running all of this from within a docker container (to manage dependencies) that I start with the following script:

```
DOCKER="docker"
IMAGE="gcr.io/gem5-test/ubuntu-22.04_all-dependencies"

${DOCKER} run \
  --rm \
  -u `id -u`:`id -g`  \
  -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -v /etc/group:/etc/group:ro \
  -v `realpath home`:/home/`id -un` \
  -v `realpath ../gem5`:/gem5 \
  -w /gem5 \
  -v `pwd`:/data
  -it ${IMAGE}
```